Maven and symbolic links -- on Gitlab runners
We have some shell-scripts under src/main/resources/. Recently, we eliminated differences between two of them, and replaced one with a symlink to another:
src/main/resources/send_html_email.sh -> send_email.sh

When I create the package (mvn package), I get the same local symlink, as expected:
target/classes/send_html_email.sh -> send_email.sh

Unfortunately, when creating the package on a Gitlab runner (jf mvn package), Maven creates a full path symlink instead of a local one:
target/classes/send_html_email.sh -> /opt/runner/builds/HhhX14kb/0/..../target/classes/send_email.sh

That's not acceptable, because that path is only valid on the runner, but does not exist on the server, where the JAR is deployed (and the scripts -- extracted). Is there any way for me to tell Maven to always use the local path, when recreating symbolic links?

Which plugin versions do you use? Which Maven version do you use? Also why putting shell scripts in a jar file? How does your pom file look like?
